# Where / How is Title determined when uploading file

Tags: media-library

[Sitecore XP] When uploading documents or images in media library the `Title` field under `Information` is populated automatically. It feels this depends also on the file extension, which is probably why I didn't find any hint in the code of `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator.CreateItem`.

It is probably in some other processor. Do you know where?

Comment: Which Sitecore version do you use? What is populated in Title field - is it the same as "alt" text? Don't you have any custom event handlers for media uploaded or item added?

Comment: @MarekMusielak It's XP 10.1 - I tried this on a vanilla 10.1 as well and there it's the same. I uploaded for example a pdf and it took the actual headline out of the document. I uploaded pptx and it took the file name.

Comment: Turns out I didn't quite use a vanilla Sitecore. There was a rogue config from a test before ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where it's proceeded but you can find some answers in the DLL `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField`, class `GetImageFieldValue`. If you're trying to customize the Title you can override the `TitleFieldName` prop. An example: https://kverheire.blogspot.com/2014/12/sitecore-problem-detected-solution.html